# How to stop receiving job emails from companies that create many job listings with the exact same description

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

There's a company that posts the same job listing 10 times every month on average on Stack Overflow Jobs.

The description of each job listing is exactly the same and it matches my job alerts. I assume that because they create a new job listing each time then it is treated as a different one by the Stack Overflow backend and as a result I receive an email notification each time. However for me it's just a clever way to spam me. Is there a way to avoid receiving such notifications or can I blacklist that company in my job alerts settings?

For details here is:

- [link to their job listing from last email](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/331644/senior-java-developer-remote-wallethub?so_medium=Email&so_source=JobAlertEmail)
- [link to their job listing from one before last email](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/327963/senior-java-developer-remote-wallethub?so_medium=Email&so_source=JobAlertEmail)

Comment: As a quicker workaround, maybe you can just set an email filter and send them to a spam folder or something? I don't know what the email looks like, but if they keep posting the same job offer over and over I assume the email title and such is also very static

Comment: Like any other job board, it doesn't take long for recruiters and shady practices to flourish.  No curators there to keep eyes on them behaving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Note: I'm a member of the software dev team at Stack Overflow that works on the Jobs/Talent product)*

There are two things you can do (which I'll detail below):

1. "Dismiss" (aka Ignore) the company and/or job listing to stop it from being included in your job alerts
2. Report abusive companies and/or problematic jobs

## 1) "Dismiss" (aka Ignore) the company and/or job listing to stop it from being included in your job alerts

In this case, you'll want to dismiss the whole company so that all the company's jobs (including future job postings) are excluded from your job alerts. But I'll also mention that you can dismiss individual jobs for the sake of other people reading this.

### To dismiss all jobs posted by a company:

Go to the Company Page for the listing company. If you're currently looking at a job listing, you can click on the company's name (just under the job title) to go to their company page.

On the Company Page, click the elipsis (`...`) button on the far right of the page header to display an actions menu.  One of the items in that menu is `Dismiss`.  **Clicking Dismiss will add the company to a list of ignored companies for you.** This applies to job alert emails, as well as job searches, recommended jobs, etc.

[image]

Additionally, if you're looking at the company search results page, when you hover over a specific company's row, there's a small `x` that appears to the far right. Clicking that `x` will also dismiss the company.

[image]

---

### To dismiss a single job:

If you don't want to completely ignore an entire company, you can ignore individual jobs instead.  This won't help in the case where the company is copy-and-pasting the same job over and over, though.

To dismiss a single job, the same process applies.  From the job's details page, you can click the `...` button and choose `Dismiss`

[image]

Or from a list of job results, hover over the job's row and click the `x` that appears to the far right of the listing.

[image]

---

## 2) Report abusive companies and/or problematic jobs

The other thing you can do, if you believe the company is acting in an improper way or posting an improper job, is "report" the company and/or job listing.  This will flag it for our customer support team to review and take action (which might be talking with the company to improve their process, removing the jobs, etc, depending on the specific issues being reported).

To report a company or job, there's a `Report` option in the same `...` menu discussed above on both the Company Page and the job details pages.
[image]

This will show a pop-up where you can describe why this company/job is problematic:
[image]

Answer (score -5):

### Option 1: Making an email filter

Creating email filters is a good way to tame your inbox from spamming with full of junk. Check your service's Help Center for details on how to create email filters. If you know that, create an filters then pick some automated actions based on filters you defined.

### Option 2: Unsubscribe emails

- Open **Edit profile and settings** > **Job alerts**.
- Look for the **Stop sending me job alerts** option. Click **Unsubscribe from all**. [image: An screenshot highlighting Unsubscribe from all button.]
- Confirm that you're want to unsubscribe by clicking **Yes, unsubscribe from all**. Please be vary that unsubscribing will delete all of your job alerts you made. [image: An screenshot highlighting Yes, unsubscribe from all button.]
- Voila! Once confirmed, all of your custom job alerts will be wiped out and also disabled the **Top job matches** option. [image: An screenshot showing only top job matches were left and disabled after unsubscribing from all.]