# Can I tell Careers not to show me a particular job/company again?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Is there a way to mark a particular job ad or employer on SO Jobs such that this job or jobs from this employer are hidden from my search results and emails? Ideally it would also allow me to add a small note saying why I'd set the hidden flag.

(I know [about this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325608/show-hide-company-jobs-in-the-search) but that's not quite what I want—I don't want to specifically exclude particular companies when making a search request, I want to see a result in a search, or from a "more like this" link, or from the list of jobs I get on my SO Jobs tab, and flag that company/job as "I don't want to see that again".)

If this doesn't already exist, consider it a feature request.

Comment: Take a look at the steps in this answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392629/682840